# Sequelize – finding point in range

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an `Address` model that has a `point` attribute of type `geometry` defined.
I want to create a function when I pass `latitude`, `longitude` and `range` and it returns all of the addresses within that range (in meters). I tried to follow what has been written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010851/sequelize-postgis-sort-by-distance-from-point) but I'm getting:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: LWGEOM_dwithin: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Point, 4326) != (Point, 0)
```

This is how I defined by `point` in the `Address` model:

```
point: {
   type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('Point'),
   allowNull: true,
},
```

And this is the function I'm trying to write:

```
const findInRangeFrom = (latitude, longitude, range) => {
  return Address.findAll({
    attributes: {
      include: [[
        Sequelize.fn(
          'ST_Distance',
          Sequelize.col('point'),
          Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', longitude, latitude),
        ),
        'distance',
      ]],
    },
    where: Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.fn(
        'ST_DWithin',
        Sequelize.col('point'),
        Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', longitude, latitude),
        range,
      ),
      true,
    ),
    order: Sequelize.literal('distance ASC'),
  });
};
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If geometries in DB are stored in the SRID 4326, then you need to set the same SRID for your test point like this:

```js
Sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID', Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', longitude, latitude), 4326)
```

If vice versa then you need to indicate SRID 4326 for the `point` column:

```js
Sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID', Sequelize.col('point'), 4326)
```

Comment: I definitely need to dive deeper into how geometry works! Thanks a lot – it solved my issue :)!